# Inserting randomly generated values into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

So currently I'm doing an assignment dealing with displaying histograms using arrays. My goal is to make a method that does the following:

Generates 100 random integers between 0 and 9, and then puts an asterisk into the appropriate column for however many time that number was generated. To clarify, suppose that the Math.random() generated eleven 0s, nine 1s, tweleve 2s, etc. The output would be:

```
  *         
* *     
* *  *  
**** ** 
**** ** *
**** *****
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
----------
0123456789
```

The problem is, I haven't been able to figure out how exactly to insert the values to display correctly. Right now my idea is, for each time a number is generated, I increment that index in an array called count. Then, I use a for each loop to find which count is the highest (max), as that will be the tallest in my histogram. I then make a 2D array with max number of rows, and 10 columns. I have nested for loops set up that will iterate over every row and every entry in the row, but I haven't been able to figure out how to insert the asterisks into the array. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void VerticalHist()
   {
      int max = 0; // initialize max

      int[] count = new int[10]; // make array to find max

      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
         int rand = (int)(Math.random() * ((9 - 0) + 1)); // generate random values

         count[rand]++;
      }

      for (int x : count) // find max 
      {
         if (x > max)
            max = x;
      }

      // System.out.println(max);
      String[][] nums2 = new String[max][10]; // create 2d array for histogram

      for (int x = max; x > 0; x--)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < nums2[x].length; i++)
         {
            // somehow insert the right amount of * for each column
         }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) // print 2d array
      {
         System.out.println();
         for (String n: nums2[i])
         {
            System.out.print(n);
         }
      }

   }
```

Comment: Advice, don't use 10 variables to save later in an array. Build the array directly and do `count[rand]++` instead of the switch

Comment: @azro That's definetely a great way to consolidate a lot of my code, thank you!